# getItemAtPosition() method in android studio returns an object. How to retrieve the item from the list as a ble device?

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

`getItemAtPosition()` method in android studio returns an object. 
Type casting it to `BluetoothDevice` does not help.
 Also, it shows a run time error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.charmi.yolo, PID: 14689
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
```

on line :

```
BluetoothDevice btDevice = (BluetoothDevice)listDevicesFound.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Thank you!

Comment: add your adapter class code

Comment: Show `listDevicesFound ` object class code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
                s.add(bt.getName());

          String bluetootPosition= s.get(position);
```